# Add Black list of application

Tags: android

I need some help. I want to add an application blacklist, I should get all applications packages in ROM and Data and then select which applications I want to add to the blacklist then save all the selected packages to "Settings.System", then check if opened app packages is in black list: "don't do some work". Else, "do some work". For example, if I check is activity running (that's ok), but it's not working because if a black list app opened and closed with the back button, app will not close and it's still running in background. Also if the app in blacklist didn't opened, the same problem as the opened app in blacklist and can't work. What is your suggestions? How can I do it?

this is so hard for explain exactly what i want but listen again:
i am working on android open sources project ROMS .
i added ability for choose Custom Activity background for all activity in Activity.java .
ok??
and now i want add blacklist of application dont set background for those apps in black list!!
first part done packages app picker as string and put to Settings.System.putString .
lock at screen shots

from this screen shots i checked 3 app

http://up.pda-planet.com/up93/pda-planet.com_Screenshot-2014-04-17-12-26-43.png

get all that 3 app packages name then save as string and put in to settings.db

http://up.pda-planet.com/up93/pda-planet.com_Screenshot-2014-04-17-12-27-26.png

i should get those packages and write some codes in activity id those apps opening don't set custom background or color!

i dont know how to add filter.

here i get excluded apps from settings.db

```
public static Set<String> mExcludedApps = new HashSet<String>();

String excludedApps= Settings.System.getString(
            getContentResolver(),
            "excluded_apps");

createExcludedAppsSet(excludedApps);


private void createExcludedAppsSet(String excludedApps) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(excludedApps))
        return;
    String[] appsToExclude = excludedApps.split("\\|");
    mExcludedApps = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(appsToExclude));
}
```

also i know i should do some things with

```
 if(!mExcludedApps.contains() && xyz==1)
 { don't do some works
 }
 else( do some things
 }
```

but dont know contains what.

@njzk2, @kabuko, @Aleks G, @laalto, @Shankar Damodaran

check now.

final edit:

i done it!

after i tried many method finally i go it working.

```
!mExcludedApps.contains(this.getPackageName())
```

Thanks All

Armin(Biftor).

Comment: this is not very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i done it!

after i tried many method finally i go it working.

```
!mExcludedApps.contains(this.getPackageName())
```

Thanks All

Armin(Biftor).